# After modification of Google Groups, permission is not reflected in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

1. I give READ permission to GROUP1 on FOLDER1
2. Already existing members in GROUP1 can find FOLDER1 in Shared Folder list (Good)
3. I add new member called JOHN in GROUP1
4. JOHN is not able to find FOLDER1 in Google Drive or using google drive sdk (VERY BAD)

I am creating an application that rely on groups for google drive permission. This is a blocker now.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue or is there a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As per resolution given in [Resolve common Google Drive issues](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490106?hl=en)  in Google Apps Administrator Help:

> The Shared with Me view shows only items that have been shared with you explicitly. This includes items shared with you via a small group (with up to 200 members). If an item is shared with a larger group, it won’t automatically show in your Drive unless you click the link in the sharing invitation email.

With this, you must send a sharing invitation email to JOHN with the link to the shared folder/file. John can access the document through that link.

Answer (score 0):

As teyman mentioned this is a known issue/feature of Google Drive. To workaround you could:

- after adding member, remove group acl on Drive folder and re-add so new member is evaluated properly.
- provide email, Google Site or other link to new member which direct user to folder so that they can find in Drive.
- as the new member, add 'root' as a parent of the folder so that folder appears in new member's My Drive.